# Compressing Folder Structure with specific filtering

Tags: filesystems, backup, tar, archive

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/foo
/foo/bar
/foo/bar2
/foo/bar3
```

Within each folder (including `/foo`) I have files with names ending `.txt`. However, I want to exclude these files from `/foo` and I want to include the ones from /foo/bar /foo/bar2 etc.

However, if I do it like this:

```
tar cvfz foo.tgz --exclude="/foo/*.txt" /foo
```

I miss ALL `.txt` files in the complete hierarchy, and not only the ones in `/foo`.

Does somebody know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can do that with just tar, since `--exclude` seems to only accept glob-style patterns. But you could get a list of files with find and then filter those with grep using regular expressions.

```
find foo -type f -print0 | grep -z -v '^foo/[^/]*.txt$' | tar cvf foo.tgz --null -T -
```

The options `-print0`, `-z` and `--null` instruct the respective commands to use a null-byte instead of a newline to separate records (filenames). This is good practice, since some files may contain unexpected characters.